# JavaScript Needs to Send Esc Character \n or Text Return <p> to HTML/Browser

Tags: javascript, html, safari, client-server

1) When executing JavaScript in the interpreter - I can use an esc sequence to put some text on a second line 
NOTE: the value of myHeading.textContent was different in this screen shot than in the succeeding two

```
   > myHeading.textContent + " \n How are things?"
   < "Joshua Tree is swell, Laurel Ruth Shimer 
   How are things?" = $1
```

2) But when I use the same idea testing by calling html from a browser (Safari), the '\n' is, I would think, just seen as
  though I had done this within html - HTML doesn't do anything special when I put something on the next line. This makes sense, of course.

```
   var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
   myHeading.textContent = 'Good to see you again, ' + storedName +  ' \n    
  Write me again soon.' ;
```

[image]
 3) If I attempt to add an html tag,

, that tag is just included as part of the text. It's not read by the html engine (I don't know what to call that) as actual characters

```
   var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
   myHeading.textContent = 'Good to see you again, ' + storedName +  ' <p>  
   Write me again soon.' ;
```

[image]
  ...

I a (maybe two?) Stackoverflow responses about putting html into an array, but I don't think that is the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst your shell *does* understand what `\n` represents, modern browsers do not. To represent a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) on a web page, you should use the [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) element instead.

Now, as you've already experienced, you cannot interpolate an HTML element using the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property. This is because the `textContent` property represents the **text** of an element, *not* the **html** -- any string you set will be treated as **text**.

To set the inner **html** of an element, use the 
[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property.

Something like this should work for your needs:

```
myHeading.innerHTML = 
    'Good to see you again, ' + storedName +  ' <br>  Write me again soon.' ;
```

Comment: Alex's answer points out why it's really important that I'm working on reading the Flannigan O'Reilly JavaScript (Rhino) book straight through! I didn't yet know enough to look up 'innerHTML' in the index. However, it's also pretty useful to stop and make up examples like this, that put all the code snippets I try out together, and work with the 3 elements of the Client Side. I like studying JavaScript this way much better than using a tutorial based book, because my own interests keep me more motivated.