# Put a new line in <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to put a new line in a `<p>` (html code):

```
<p id="text_folder"><p>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$('#text_folder').text("first"+"\n"+"second");
```

But in my `<p>` tag the result is
first
second
and not:
first
second
Anyone can help me?

Comment: I answered a similar question recently. Maybe you'll find it useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213900/javascript-needs-to-send-esc-character-n-or-text-return-p-to-html-browser/37213963#37213963

Comment: you should use `<br>` for this purpose and not `\n`

Comment: Use `<br>` instead of `\n`

Comment: `$('#text_folder').html("first"+"<br />"+"second");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
('#text_folder').html("first"+"<br />"+"second")
```

try this

Answer (score 5):

In HTML, all whitespace characters (including newlines) are interpreted as spaces. To put a line break in a `p` element, you use a [`br` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element):

```
$("#text_folder").html("first<br>second");
```

If your "first" and "second" are externally-sourced (from the user, etc.), you'll want to make sure that you deal with any special HTML characters in them first. There are a couple of ways to do that; I find `replace` the simplest of them:

```
function escapeHTML(str) {
    return str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
}
```

so then

```
var first = /*...get input from user or whatever...*/;
var second = /*...get input from user or whatever...*/;
$("#text_folder").html(escapeHTML(first) + "<br>" + escapeHTML(second));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are working with HTML and thus have to use html() instead of text()

```
$('#text_folder').html("first<br>second");
```

Answer (score 1):

Write code like this

```
$('#text_folder').html("first<br>second");
```